# Grid layout solution css

Tags: html, css

I need a responsive grid layout system for some web pages, and depending on the category there is a need for a different layout, as you can see in the image attached.

I been looking around for some solutions and all that I have seen seems to be outdated, what is the best option for this nowadays? I am open for any js library or css templates.

Thank you

[image: grid layout]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at Bootstrap? It provides a pretty good solution for creating grid formats using HTML classes.

Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

More about the Bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/